# Php, codeigniter, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to retrieve student scores on each  subject from database table infront of  their names..

My Model

```
public function getscore($class, $term, $session)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT scores FROM allscores WHERE   class ='$class' AND term ='$term' AND session ='$session' AND       scores !=0");
    return $query;
}
```

controller

```
public function showscores()
{
    $class=$this->input->post('classes');
    $term=$this->input->post('term');
    $session=$this->input->post('session');
    $data['query_scores'] = $this->model->getscore($class,$term,    $session);
    $this->load->view('scoresheet', $data);
}
```

view page

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <?php 
        foreach ($query_scores->result() as $row)
        {
    ?>
            <td><?php echo $row->scores; ?></td>
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: student name is listed horizontally on the left side of d page, subject names is displayed vertically as the heading.
 My challenge is to display the score o each subject under d subject name for each students. 
 Your assistance in this regard would be  very appreciated.

Comment: Is this return proper array in $query_scores->result()

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getscore($class, $term, $session)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT scores FROM allscores WHERE   class ='$class' AND term ='$term' AND session ='$session' AND       scores !=0");
    return $query-result();
}
```

Use `result()` to format and show thing from database.

Answer (score 0):

Use following table format to display subject names

```
<table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <td> SUB1 </td> <td> SUB2 </td> <td> SUB3 </td> 
     </tr>
    </thead>
```

Now use your code for Corresponding Content.
The exact PHP code for displaying the subject score will depend on your database structure. For more clarification, please share your database table structure.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

Model:
**note:** change field name and query structure to match yours

normaly this will require a join but this is a basic example for you to get the idea

```
    public function getscore($class, $term, $session){
         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT  scores,student_id ,student_name, subject_id,subject_name , FROM allscores WHERE  class ='$class' AND term ='$term' AND session ='$session' AND  scores !=0");
         return $query; 
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public function showscores(){
       $class=$this->input->post('classes');
       $term=$this->input->post('term');
       $session=$this->input->post('session');
       $data['query_scores'] = $this->model->getscore($class,$term,    $session);

       // create array to hold the new organized data;
       $list = array();
       // list['scores'] will hold the student scores;
       // list['students']  = will hold the student names
       // list['subjects'] =  will hold the subjects names

      // loop throught the result 
      foreach ($query_scores->result() as $row){
         $list['scores'][$row->student_id][$row->subject_id] = $row->scores;
         $list['students'][$row->student_id]= $row->student_name;
         $list['subjects'][$row->subject_id]= $row->subject_name;
      }

      $this->load->view('scoresheet', $list);
    }
```

view page:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
     <?php 
       foreach ($subjects as $subject){
         echo "<td>".$subject."</td>";  // will display subjects names on the first row
       }
     ?> </tr> <?php
       $column = 0;
       foreach ($scores as $key=>$element){
         echo "<tr>"; 
         echo "<td>".$students[$key]."</td>"; // will display student names on the first col
         foreach ($element as $subKey=>$subelement){
            echo "<td>".$subelement."</td>";
         }
         echo "<tr>";
     <?php 
       } ?>
 </table>
```